# OAuth popup redirects to localhost and closes instantly - Phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, oauth.io

I am trying to integrate twitter with my PhoneGap app, but for some reason my oauth pop up seems to appear for a second with the correct link to twitter, but then change to localhost and just close down.

I have included `<access origin="api.twitter.com" />` in my config file  and have also tried `<access origin="*" />` but have had no luck.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../plugins/com.oauthio.plugins.oauthio/www/oauth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function twitterLogin(){
    OAuth.initialize('nFIvCI_XGWCKRKtRjmIkWBcGbRo');    

    OAuth.popup('twitter', {cache: true}).done(function(result) {

 result.post('/1.1/statuses/update.json', {
  data: {
    status: "hello world!"
  }
})

}).fail(function(err) {

  alert("fail");
})     
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="twitterLogin()">twitter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

to your config.xml file?

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html